# Parse json in Java android studio

Tags: java, android, json

I have this code to parse a json in Java, but problem is my json looks like this

```
{"ime":"Alen","prezime":"Osmanagi\u0107","test":[1,2,3,4,5],"test2":{"1":"test","2":"555","test":"888","om":"hasd"}}
```

And my java code for parsing looks like :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListView listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.jsonList);
                if ( true) {
                    try {
                       JSONArray mojNiz = response.getJSONArray("");

                        List<JSON> noviJSON = new ArrayList<>();
                        //Popuniti podacima
                        for (int i = 0; i < mojNiz.length(); i++) {
                            JSON jsonObj = new JSON();
                            JSONObject mojObj = mojNiz.getJSONObject(i);
                            jsonObj.setIme(mojObj.getString(KEY_NAME));
                           // jsonObj.setPrezime(mojObj.getString(KEY_DOB));
                          //jsonObj.setPrezime(mojObj.getString(KEY_DESIGNATION));
                            noviJSON.add(jsonObj);
                        }

                        adapter = new Adapter(noviJSON, getApplicationContext());

                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Problem u loadiranjuz podataka",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```

How can I parse this particular json string ???

Comment: This is not the efficient way to parse JSON. Create POJOs and use GSON and let GSON do the parsing for you. Take a look at this blog.
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the JSONObject and then the array inside it

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String objectIme = jsonObject.getString("ime");
String prezime = jsonObject.getString("prezime");
```

The above line will get the whole object and from this object you can get other objects and the array test1 and test2 like below then you can loop through that array like you did

```
    JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray("test1"));
    JSONArray jArray2 = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray("test2"));

 for (int i = 0; i < jArray1 .length(); i++) {
                            JSON jsonObj = new JSON();
                            JSONObject mojObj = jArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                            jsonObj.setIme(mojObj.getString(KEY_NAME));

                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing your json wrong. Your json starts with jsonObject instead of jsonArray. So in your case you have to start like this
**(assuming that your result variable of onPostExecute method has the json string)**

```
JSONObject mojNiz = new JSONObject(result);
```

Now from the above `mojNiz` object you can get your json array

Comment: json can't be url.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "{\"ime\":\"Alen\",\"prezime\":\"Osmanagi\\u0107\",\"test\":[1,2,3,4,5],\"test2\":{\"1\":\"test\",\"2\":\"555\",\"test\":\"888\",\"om\":\"hasd\"}}";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
        jsonObject.getString("ime");
        jsonObject.getString("prezime");

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("test");

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            list.add((Integer) jsonArray.get(i));

        }

        JSONObject testObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("test2");
        testObject.getString("1");
        testObject.getString("2");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```